# Unicode error when loading a json_encoded PHP array from memcached

Tags: php, python, json, memcached

I need to transfer a PHP associative array to further processing using python. The python code however using pylibmc is unable to load the string from memcached, throwing this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 32: invalid continuation byte
```

I wrote a little tester. The PHP code to create the memcached data:

```
<?php
$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$data = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  $index = "ti" . $i;
  $data += [$index => "test string $i"];
}

$mc->delete('test');
$mc->add('test', json_encode($data), 60);

$reverse = $mc->get('test');
echo "$reverse\n";  // prints {"ti0":"test string 0" ...... "ti99":"test string 99"} as expected

$reverse_array = json_decode($reverse, true);

echo $reverse_array['ti10'] . "\n";
//prints 'test string 10' as expected
?>
```

so this works fine writing to memcached from PHP and reading it back.

On the python side, this is the code I use to read it in:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pylibmc
import json

mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True, behaviors={"cas": True, "tcp_nodelay": True,"ketama": True})

temp = json.loads(mc.get("test"))
```

When running the python code, this is the output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mctest.py", line 7, in <module>
    temp = json.loads(mc.get("test")))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 32: invalid continuation byte
```

If I create a non-associative array in PHP and share that through memcached, things work fine.

Two further options I've tried:

adding utf8_encode to make sure it's properly encoded:

```
$mc->add('test', utf8_encode(json_encode($data)), 60);
```

adding JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to the json_encode function:

```
$mc->add('test', json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), 60);
```

both result in identical outcomes on the python side.

Bit at a loss here - any ideas welcome!

Comment: It is not loading a string but binary data and there is no issues loading it but decoding it for printing.

Comment: unfortunately not true. adding e.g. temp = json.loads(mc.get("test")) results in the same error, without displaying the data.

Comment: It is the same issue. `json.loads` wants a string so it tries to decode the binary data. The data is either text encoded with a different codec or not text.

Comment: any suggestions on how to avoid loading this as a string? even temp = mc.get("test") fails with the same error.

Comment: This is getting more bizarre the further I investigate. Modifying the example above to write a flat array works when calling the PHP and python code from the terminal, but causes the same unicode error when the PHP script is called via the web server. Some encoding somewhere is getting stuffed up.

Comment: So I was terribly wrong. I suggest you update your question to make clear which of the two class is raising the exception. Unfortunately I don't know much about memcache and I can barely read php. But it looks very weird to me that `mc.get` just assumes that the data is utf8-encoded text when it cannot be guaranteed. Maybe that can be configured in the client instantiation or the call to `get`? Isn't there a way to make `get` give you just the bytes without trying to decode them? Or using a different codec?

Comment: pylibmc is quite limited that way, so I've just tried using a different memcached implementation - pymemcache - to read the data. The read now works, but the data it receives is mostly garbled and of no discernible encoding type. The PHP environment is set to force ASCII text when talking to memcached. That doesn't appear to be honoured.

Comment: thanks Goyo, your response helped guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to determine the encoding of the resulting string retrieved from memcached via pymemcache, it occurred to me that the string didn't look like any known encoding, I confirmed this using chardet as well as cchardet.

After some more digging at the PHP end, I discovered that the PHP memcached module adulterates the strings it saves to memcached by compressing the data!

Solution was to add this line to the /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini file:

```
memcached.compression_threshold=9999999999
```

Now the data comes into python as it should!